# Binding Navigator Navigation Mixed

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sdf, bindingnavigator

I have a sdf database setup. The problem comes when I click the movenext button. SO when I keep Moving through the records it goes in this order: 23, 24, 25, **32**, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34... and so On.
But its supposed to be 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32.. and so on right?

**These numbers are auto generated record ID which are Incremented every new record**

when i view the records in datagridview the order is good. So any ideas how i can resolve this?

**UPDATE**
Sorry for the late reply. I have been trying to create an alternative route for record navigation so that it goes in order of the ID number. I have created a variable **Cur_navID** where the current records ID is saved. Every time next or previous buttons are pressed the next record in order will be displayed. But with thousands of record this method tends to be a bit vague. so anyways heres the main codes

Here is the code for:

New Record

```
 Private Sub NewRecord()
    If Not isEditing = True Then
        Enable_edit()
        id += 1
        Me.BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.PerformClick()

        Cust_nameTextBox.Clear()
        ContactTextBox.Clear()
        RemTextBox.Clear()
        GradeTextBox.Clear()
        SchoolTextBox.Clear()
        V_numberTextBox.Clear()
        Student_nameTextBox.Clear()

        M7_idLabel1.Text = String.Format("{0:0000}", id)
        date_pick.Value = DateTime.Now

        StatusComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0
        StatusComboBox.Text = "To Be Done"
        setStatus(StatusComboBox.Text)

        Cust_nameTextBox.Focus()
    ElseIf isEditing = True Then
        Dim di As DialogResult = MsgBox("Do you want to save the current record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel)
        If di = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Or di = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            SaveRecord()
            NewRecord()
        ElseIf di = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
            Canceledit()
        ElseIf di = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Save Record

```
Private Sub SaveRecord()
    Try
        '// for customers with multiple lists. easier entry

        lastmember.cust_name = Cust_nameTextBox.Text
        lastmember.contact = ContactTextBox.Text
        lastmember.grade = GradeTextBox.Text
        lastmember.remks = RemTextBox.Text
        Cust_nameTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        Cust_nameTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        Dim MySource As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
        MySource.Add(lastmember.cust_name)
        Cust_nameTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource

        Me.ListsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.PerformClick()
        Disable_edit()

        MsgBox("Record Saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        'AppWait(700)
        'ListsBindingSource.MoveLast()


        Cust_nameTextBox.Focus()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' MsgBox("Please Fill in Customer Name, Contact and Grade Boxes", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Binding Navigator Save Item code

```
Private Sub ListsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.ListsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.BooksListDataSet)
    My.Settings.ID = id
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

And in form load event

```
    ' ### Load data into the 'BooksListDataSet.Lists' table.
    Me.ListsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BooksListDataSet.Lists)
    Me.BindingNavigatorMoveLastItem.PerformClick()


    ' ### Update counter if database changed
    Dim chek As Boolean = MAXID(BooksListDataSet.Tables("Lists")) = String.Format("{0:0000}", My.Settings.ID.ToString)
    If chek = False Then
        MsgBox("Database has been updated. Application will restart to compensate the changes.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        ' My.Settings.ID = Me.BooksListDataSet.Tables("Lists").Rows(BooksListDataSet.Tables("Lists").Rows.Count - 1).Item(0).ToString
        My.Settings.ID = MAXID(BooksListDataSet.Tables("Lists"))
        My.Settings.Save()
        Application.Restart()
    Else
    End If


    ' ### Take backup
    If My.Settings.backup_date = Nothing Then
        Dim di As DialogResult = MsgBox("Do you want to create a backup database?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel)
        If di = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Or di = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            '//backup database
            If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath.ToString, My.Settings.ID.ToString & "BooksList.sdf.BAK")) Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath.ToString, "BooksList.sdf"), Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath.ToString, My.Settings.ID.ToString & "BooksList.sdf.BAK"))
                My.Settings.backup_date = Date.Today
                My.Settings.Save()
            End If

        Else
            'do nothing
        End If
    ElseIf Not My.Settings.backup_date = Date.Today Or My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath.ToString, My.Settings.ID.ToString & "BooksList.sdf.BAK")) = False Then
        Dim di2 As DialogResult = MsgBox("Do you want to create todays backup database now?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel)
        If di2 = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Or di2 = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            '//backup database
            If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath.ToString, My.Settings.ID.ToString & "BooksList.sdf.BAK")) Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath.ToString, "BooksList.sdf"), Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath.ToString, My.Settings.ID.ToString & "BooksList.sdf.BAK"))
                My.Settings.backup_date = Date.Today
                My.Settings.Save()
            End If

        Else
            'do nothing
        End If
    End If

    ' ### Load Autopcomplete list
    Dim autocompleteList As New System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("Schools.ACL")
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            autocompleteList.Add(reader.ReadLine())
        End While
    End Using
    SchoolTextBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    SchoolTextBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    SchoolTextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocompleteList

    ' ### Focus next textbox on enter function part
    textBoxes.Add(Cust_nameTextBox)
    textBoxes.Add(ContactTextBox)
    textBoxes.Add(RemTextBox)
    textBoxes.Add(GradeTextBox)
    textBoxes.Add(SchoolTextBox)
    textBoxes.Add(V_numberTextBox)
    textBoxes.Add(Student_nameTextBox)

    Disable_edit()
    Cur_navID = MAXID(Me.BooksListDataSet.Tables("Lists"))
    Me.ListsBindingSource.Position = Cur_navID
```

Comment: What do they look like in your sdf?

Comment: Also please add code so we can better assist you...

Comment: in sdf file its in correct order. 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32.... which part of the code should I post? as i have no idea where this happpens. so if u could advice which part of the code??

Comment: How your binding ect would be a great start